# How does SO sort by votes?

Tags: discussion

There is an interesting [write up on ranking by votes](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).  Apologies if this has been asked already, I couldn't see it.

The tl;dr is (#positive votes - #negative votes) is a bad idea, also (% of positive votes) is a bad idea.  However there is a formula that does the right thing called a Lower bound of Wilson score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter which [reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx#L70) and a number of others use.

Does stack overflow use this?

Comment: Nope: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49787/270345

Comment: @muru - Thanks - I guess Ill close this as a dupe then.

Comment: It's on [meta.se], so you can't close as a dupe. :(

Comment: @muru - Sorry, was not clear by reading the post, does the 'nope' mean that SO does not use the reddit style ranking?

Comment: SO does not use the reddit style ranking. It's a plain up - down score with random tie-breaking. The linked post is a very popular answer suggesting its use, which you can support.

Comment: @muru Actually post date is used as a tiebreaker, unless the posts were posted within 10? minutes of each other, at which point they're ordered randomly.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

We are happy fans of wrong solution number one: sorting by their score which is equal to positive votes minus negative votes. Anyways, the `votes` tab is used to sort questions by their current score not by some intricate equation only some people can understand.